# How to distinguish between two classes with the same name (and namespace) in 2 DLL's?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, namespaces

I've got two DLL's - a `Common.dll` and a `CFW.Infrastructure.Sdk.dll`. Both DLL's contain the following class:

```
CFW.Common.Hashing.BlockHasher
```

I have a *test project* that references both DLL's. When I try to test the BlockHasher, I get the following error:

[image: Blockhasher exists in both DLL's]

I like to test the one in the `CFW.Infrastructure.Sdk.dll`. Because the fully qualified names are the same I can't fix this with a 'normal' using.

Comment: That's what aliases are for (if you've ever noticed that feature in the property grid when you've got a reference selected in Solution Explorer). Or here's the [command line variant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173212.aspx)

Comment: Use external aliases as it described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173212.aspx

Comment: I'm not familiar with it. I'll check it out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[External aliasses](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173212.aspx) can be used.

#### 1. Add an alias to the DLL reference

Open the solution explorer. Navigate to the DLL and add an `alias` to it.
[image: Properties of the reference]

#### 2. Reference the alias

Add the following the the C# file (must be on top):

```
extern alias Sdk;
```

#### 3.Add some `usings` to distinguish:

I've added the classes that gave problems as usings:

```
using BlockHasher = Sdk.CFW.Common.Hashing.BlockHasher; 
using SigningAlgorithm = Sdk.CFW.Common.Hashing.SigningAlgorithm;
```

#### 4.Done!

Got the idea from the [Extern Alias Walkthrough](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ansonh/2006/09/27/extern-alias-walkthrough/).